# How does a CPU with 2 core or more works and hyperthreading

Tags: cpu, hyper-threading

I got a little confused,when there is 2 cores or more to a CPU does it mean that two processes can run on those cores or two different threads?.When there is hyper-threading does two threads run the same time in the core?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is hyper-threading and how does it work?](http://superuser.com/questions/122536/what-is-hyper-threading-and-how-does-it-work), [Hyper-Threading and Dual-Core, What's the Difference?](http://superuser.com/questions/133082/hyper-threading-and-dual-core-whats-the-difference) etc. These concepts have been discussed many times already. Do search before posting a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are threads, and what do they do in the processor?](http://superuser.com/questions/329904/what-are-threads-and-what-do-they-do-in-the-processor)

Answer (score 0):

> when there is 2 cores or more to a CPU does it mean that two processes can run on those cores or two different threads?

It means that two threads can run at the same time. Those two threads may or may not belong to different processes. Processes use threads to get work done.

> When there is hyper-threading does two threads run the same time in the core?

Yes, exactly. The two threads share the core's execution resources.